# Notification on unsuspension?

Tags: support, notifications, account-suspension, email-notification

I was just wondering, when a user has been unsuspended from an SE site, do they get any form of notification about it (e.g.: email)?

Comment: Pretty sure there is no notification, but not certain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, no notifications exist for when a suspension expires or is removed.

It is easy enough to find out if it is in effect, after all - just visit the user page.

There is not compelling benefit for such a notification.

Comment: I don't think OP means when it expires "naturally", but when a moderator unsuspends the account manually. (e.g. when the suspension was done by mistake)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - either way, no such notification (for similar reasons)

Comment: When it expires after the set time I agree, as the time is known. But if I would be suspended for 7 days, then after 2 days someone decides to save me and unsuspend, I would like to know. I won't check the account all day long, knowing it's probably pointless.

Comment: @nicael I know, that's what Oded just confirmed, but when done manually I disagree with this behavior.

Comment: @Sha But it doesn't really matter - if you still visit the site regularly, you'll notice it, otherwise why remind?

Comment: I meant naturally expiring ones, because there was someone suspended who was trolling and targeting me and their suspension ends in a few months so I was hoping that they would not be notified because they would probably just come back again. Though my question could be extended to cover manual unsuspensions.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Don't worry, they wait. Patiently wait. Wait. Wait. :P

Comment: Usually if we're in a position where we are manually unsuspending someone, it will be accompanied by a mod message or support email explaining why, etc which would generate a notification and/or email for them. I don't know any situations where we've just blindly unsuspended a user without telling them.